# Difficult sets of Equations, counting

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> Let $ m$ be the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation $ 4x+3y+2z=2009$, and let $ n$ be the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation $ 4x+3y+2z=2000$. Find the remainder when $ m-n$ is divided by $ 1000$.

**Please no complete solutions.**

$4x + 3y + 2z = 2009$ first.

$2z = 2009 - 4x - 3y$

$\implies 2z \equiv 2 - 4x \pmod{3} \implies z \equiv 1 - 2x \pmod{3}$.So $z = 1 - 2x + 3k$.

$4x + 3y + 2 - 4x +  6k = 2009$.

$3y = 2007 + 6k$.

$ y = (2007 + 6k)/3 = 2007/3 + 2k = 669 + 2k$.

But that doesnt work properly.

I literally cant do ANYTHING, I am very stuck!

**EDIT:**

$x, y, z = 1$ each.

$3y + 2z = 2005 \implies 3y \equiv 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{2} \implies y = 1 + 2k, z = \frac{2005 - 3(1 + 2k)}{2} = 1001 - 3k.$

$2x + z = 1003 \implies z \equiv 1 \pmod{2}, z = 1 + 2k, x = \frac{1002 - 2k}{2} = 501 - k$

$4x + 3y = 2007 \implies 3y \equiv 3 \pmod{4} \implies y = 1 + 4k, x = \frac{2007 - 3y}{4} = 1002 - 3k$

I just cannot find how many $k$ values will work.

Comment: Please check the $y=1$ case again. Do you mean $z=1+2k$?

Comment: @mathlove, yes, its a typo?

Comment: @mathlove, also what next/

Comment: For the $z=1$ case, it should be $x=501-3k$. Then, for $x=1$, $k=0,1,\cdots,333$. For $y=1$, $k=0,1,\cdots,500$. For $z=1$, $k=0,1,\cdots,166$. Finally, note that both $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1001)$ and $(x,y,z)=(501,1,1)$ satisfy $4x+3y+2z=2009$. Now I gave you all hints from which you should be able to get the answer.

Comment: @mathlove, okay I think I got it. there are $333 - 0 + 1 = 334$ soln. Then $501 + 167 + 2 = 1004$ total solutions? I seem to be off by $4$?

Comment: No, it should be $(334-1)+(501-2)+(167-1)+2=1000$ total solutions. Please consider the meaning of this calculation yourself.

Comment: @mathlove, I tried for a long time to convince myself, but I dont see how you are getting these numbers. why $334 - 1$, why $501 -2

Comment: "334" includes $(1,1,1001)$. "501" includes $(1,1,1001)$ and $(501,1,1)$. "167" includes $(501,1,1)$. So, "334-1" means that the number of solutions such that $x=1$ and $(x,y,z)\not=(1,1,1001)$, and so on. So, the number of the total solutions, which is $m-n$, can be expressed as $(334-1)+(501-2)+(167-1)+2$. (the $+2$ represents $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1001),(501,1,1)$.)

Comment: @mathlove, thanks for clearing that up, I think I am going to let my mind rest for a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ is a solution of $4x+3y+2z=2000$, then $(x,y,z)=(a+1,b+1,c+1)$ is a solution of $4x+3y+2z=2009.$

Now find the number of the solutions $(x,y,z)$ of $4x+3y+2z=2009$ such that either $x,y$ or $z$ equals $1$. (**note that this is $m-n$**.)

Comment: Proof that $(x, y, z) = (a + 1, b + 1, c + 1)$? Wait: $4(a + 1) + 3(b + 1) + 2(c +1) = 4a + 4 + 3b + 3 + 2c + 2 = 4a + 3b + 2c + 9$

Comment: @Amad27: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Then it is a bijection correct

Comment: @Amad27: No, since $a,b,c\ge 1$,  we have $a+1,b+1,c+1\ge 2$. So, you'll need to consider when $x=1$ or $y=1$ or $z=1$ for $4x+3y+2z=2009$. This is the second sentence in my answer.

Comment: $z=1$ is the case. But is this the only exception?

Comment: @Amad27: Well, it's time for you to consider yourself...I think. You want to find the number of solutions $(x,y,z)$ such that $4x+3y+2z=2009$ and $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry if I am bugging too much, but what does the product of $x-1$ etc have to do with the solutions?

Comment: @Amad27: $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=0$ means that $x=1$ or $y=1$ or $z=1$. This means that we want to find the number of solutions $(x,y,z)$ of $4x+3y+2z=2009$ such that either $x,y$ or $z$ equals $1$. So, for $x=1$, consider the number of solutions $(y,z)$ for $4\cdot 1+3y+2z=2009$, i.e. $3y+2z=2005$. For $y=1$... and so on.

Comment: Yes @mathlove, I understood that, but what is the motivation?

Comment: @Amad27: As I wrote in my answer, if $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ is a solution of $4x+3y+2z=2000$, then $(x,y,z)=(a+1,b+1,c+1)$ is a solution of $4x+3y+2z=2009$. Here, note that $a+1,b+1,c+1\ge 2$. This means that we don't count the solutions $(x,y,z)$ for $4x+3y+2z=2009$ such that either $x,y$ or $z$ equals $1$. So, we now know that $m-n$ is the number of solutions $(x,y,z)$ for $4x+3y+2z=2009$ such that either $x,y$ or $z$ equals $1$. This is the motivation.

Comment: Okay for the solutions $/ge 2$, both equations have the same  number of solutions, now for $x = 1$. We have: $3y + 2z = 2005$ which gives: $(1, 667 - 2k, 1 + 3k)$, $(3k, 669 - 4k, 1)$, and $(501 - k, 1, 2k)$. For $k \in \{0, ..., 332  \}$ for $x = 1$?

Comment: @Amad27: Note that neither $(x,y,z)=(1,667-2k,1+3k)$ nor $(x,y,z)=(501-k,1,2k)$ satisfies $4x+3y+2z=2009$.

Comment: I am adding an edit with the complete attempt, please read it!

Comment: edit made, I may have screwed things up, please look!